# Mongoose subdocs: cannot call method call to of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reference, mongoose, document

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
    at Array.MongooseArray._cast (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:78:15)
    at Object.map (native)
    at Array.MongooseArray.push (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:187:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/accounts/routes/me.js:29:27)
    at callbacks (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:37)
    at Promise.module.exports (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/middleware/load_user.js:15:13)
    at Promise.addBack (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:66:38)
    at Promise.complete (/Users/bodo/Documents/Repositories/EnabreNode/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:77:20)
```

I actually want to built a quite simple schema:

```
{
    username: "bodo",
    email: "info@example.com",
    contacts: [{ 
        user: { username: "john", email: "john@google.com" }, 
        messages: [
            { 
                sender: { username: "bodo", email: "info@example.com" },
                receiver: { username: "john", email: "john@google.com" },
                body: "How are you these days?"
            },
            { 
                sender: { username: "john", email: "john@google.com" },                                       
                receiver: { username: "bodo", email: "info@example.com" },
                body: "I am totally fine?"
            } 
        ]
    }]
};
```

The contacts attribute contains a contacts subdocument which holds the user object of the actual contact (as reference) and later on some meta data like hasAcceptedContactRequest, contactSince, etc.
Additionally I also save messages subdocs which are from a chat. These message subdocs contain the message as body attribute and who has send or received it. The sender and receiver are again references to a full user object which can be populated.

So much in theory. I now have created these schemas:

**UserSchema**

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ContactSchema = require('./contact');

var UserSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({

    username: { 
        type: String, 
        index: { unique: true, sparse: true }, 
        required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        index: { unique: true, sparse: true }, 
        required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true
    },

    contacts: [ContactSchema]

});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'Users');
```

**ContactSchema**

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MessageSchema = require('./message');

var ContactSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({

    user: {
        ref: "User",
        type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },

    messages: [MessageSchema]

});

module.exports = ContactSchema;
```

**MessageSchema**

```
var MessageSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({

    body: {
        type: String
    },

    sender: {
        ref: "User",
        type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },

    receiver: {
        ref: "User",
        type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }

});

module.exports = ContactSchema;
```

**That is the route**

```
app.put('/me', loadUser, function(req, res, next) {
    var user = req.user;
    var body = req.body;

    if (body.contacts) {
        body.contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
            user.contacts.push({ user: contact });
        });
    }

    console.log(req.user);

    user.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(200);
    });
});
```

Solution:
As johnyHK mentioned there was a problem using the module system of node. I have accidentally 
exported the schemas as models. You now see the corrected examples above. So they should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order of your schema definitions is the same in your code, you need to reorder them so that the referenced schemas are fully defined when used.

So that would be:

1. `MessageSchema`
2. `ContactSchema`
3. `UserSchema`

Comment: Hi, how do I order them? Currently the route requires user.js which requires contact.js which requires message.js or do you mean putting them all together?

Comment: So I merged the Schemas all together in one file and see there it works! So your idea is right I will search how to control module order

Comment: okay sorry I did not found anything usefull about that problem. Couly you provide an example how I say require() to wait until the module is loaded?

Comment: @kyogron As long as you've got your schemas split up into separate files as you describe and your `require` statements are at the top of the files, then that should work.  `require` is synchronous.

Comment: @kyogron Your example document at the top doesn't match your schema definitions which contain a lot of `ObjectId` references.  Can you update your question to show the contents of `body.contacts` that you're pushing to the `user` doc?

Comment: I found the problems: 1. I have just copy and pasted the module.exports of the user schema which exports the user schema as mongoose.model. That is stupid when I actually require the schemas... The second problem was that I somehow cannot declare a subdoc array with an object contacts: [{ type: ContactSchema }]. You have to use [ContactSchema]. Now it works actually. What is your question with body.contacts about? body.contacts only contains an array of user ids. If you want to know where username, etc. are set that is a different route

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   user : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true }
```